# android - transit from activity to fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

my app has a quite few activities(pages). And now, I want to make all my pages into `Fragment`. I want to keep my menu bar remain the same throughout the entire activity cycle and only replace the content view. I took a look at the `Fragment` example that Google provided, but the example basically just replace the content view with some information. I want some other actions like a button in `Fragment`.

Is there a way that I can just do like

```
public class MyPage extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContent(new Intent(this, content1.class));
    setMenuView(R.layout.mymenu);
}

void onMenuClicked(int position) {
    switch (position) {
    case 1:
        setContent(new Intent(this, content2.class));
        break;
    case 2:
        setContent(new Intent(this, content3.class));
        break;
    }
}
```

so this will start my `content1` activity in the content section, and just start another activity by replacing the content section. `MyPage` will be just a wrapper.

Or is there any example of how to implement `Fragment`? I need an example that does more actions then just displaying information.

Thank you very much for the help.

**EDITED**
what I meant in the example is let's say I have a layout with just two views. One menu view on the top and a content view. I wish to start a new activity like `startActivity(new Intent(this, content2.class));` but only the content view will get updated. menu view remains the same. I believe that's how fragment can do. but my question is how can I do that? each of my activities have things like buttons, listview, spinner, expandablelistview, etc. But google's example only provide a piece of information which is not even clickable. what can I do to have more actions other than just return a view like the example from google?

Comment: I think your example is confused.  You don't setContentView to an intent, you do it to a layout.  Can you explain what you want better?

Comment: yea. i did that on purpose. I guess that was a really bad example....let me rewrite that

Comment: in my example, setContentView was not the method you usually use to set your layout. What I meant was start a new activity within the content view.

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793576/switching-between-fragment-view

Comment: This example shows only the information fragment. What if I have have button click event?

Comment: Use google.  How to respond to a button click has been answered several hundred times on this board.

Comment: I know how to respond a button click event. just setOnClickListener. the question is how to do that in a fragment?

Comment: and how to turn my activities into fragments?