# move from a fragment to another in an activity

Tags: android, fragment

From what I understand from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793576/switching-between-fragment-view#), fragments can be easily replaced with another.

However in my case, I have 2 fragments combined in scrollable Activity, so when I say "move", I mean going from the fragment left to the right or right to the left without replacing any fragment with another. Is this somehow possible?

Comment: Sometimes I don't mind a downvote, I understand that the question is lacking additional information or code. But I'm just here to learn, so if someone going to downvote, I hope I could still get an explanation. Good day to you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use ViewPager for that. And on your adapter class you will have to switch between the fragments via getItem(). Eclipse/new AndroidProject/ swipe with/out tabs. And check the example code generated by Android.

---

edit:

create xml file call it `main_activity.xml`

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Main" >
<android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
    android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#FAFAFA"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:textColor="#36466E" />
```

create a class call it `Main`

```
       public class Main extends FragmentActivity {
        SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
        ViewPager mViewPager;
        Context ctx;
        static MySQLiteHelper db;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                    getSupportFragmentManager());
            mSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

            public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
                super(fm);
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                Fragment fragment = null;
                switch(position){
                case 0:
                    fragment = new GridApp();
                break;
                case 1:
                    fragment = new ListApp();
                break;
                }
                return fragment;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 2;
            }
            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "Select App";
                case 1:
                    return "Selected Apps";
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
}
```

now create a class called `GridApp` and `ListApp`

GridApp class.

```
    public class GridApp extends Fragment {

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridpp,
                container, false);

}
}
```

ListApp class

```
        public class GridApp extends Fragment {

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listapp,
                container, false);

}
}
```

and you are done.

Comment: please give some code example for viewpager for better understandig

Comment: if it helped you, you could accept it so it be helpful for more in future. and i'm glad that i helped .