# How to remove the menu from an action bar (java)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I'm new to android development and wanted to make a tabbed application, so I started with google's file form the documentation and I would like to remove the most above part of the action bar (where the logo and the app name stands). I've tried styling it like this:

```
<resources>
<style name="ThemeHoloWithActionBar" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle</item>

    <item name="android:actionBarSize">50dip</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTabStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:minHeight">50dip</item>
</style>
```

hoping that it would push the size of the other bar to 0 but it didn't work.

Edit:
when using:

```
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
```

I Can't get the error formatted correctly so I uploaded an image :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WMw0.jpg

Comment: means u doesn't wants menu button or does not wants actionbar at all

Comment: I only want the part that contain the tabs.

Comment: Add '<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>' to your AppTheme style

Comment: getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS); for this

Comment: @Abhishek Chaubey it says cannot resolve getActivity, where should I place it?

Comment: @Xingchen doing this only causes a white bar with the app name?!

Comment: in the activity where u have inflated the view of that fragment onCreateView(

Comment: Sorry it should be Adding '<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>' together with '<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>' to your AppTheme style

Comment: @Xingchen this give me the error I'll in an update of the question.

Comment: Can you give more info of error

Comment: looks something wrong in your oncreate, in line 74, check it or attach the codes

Comment: @Xingchen okay I fixed that, but this doesn't show any tabs at all?

Comment: Yes I suppose, I will make a whole answer for your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don’t need the action bar, you can remove it from your entire app or from individual activities. This is appropriate for apps that never used the options menu or for apps in which the action bar doesn’t meet design needs (such as games). You can remove the action bar using a theme such as Theme.Holo.NoActionBar or Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar.

in style.xml add this:

```
<resources>
    <style name="NoActionBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Your style here -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

in AndroidManifest.xml add this:

```
<!-- [...] -->
    <application android:name="@style/NoActionBar"
<!-- [...] -->
```

or try with this:

```
<!-- [...] -->
    <application android:theme="@style/NoActionBar">
<!-- [...] -->
```

Comment: but I don't need the complete bar removed cuz the tabs are in the action  bar as well

Comment: remove tab and create your own

Comment: Then what would be the code to switch bfweteen  fragments @GabrielAtan ?

Comment: look this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793576/switching-between-fragment-view

Answer (score 0):

To remove actionbar, you need add:

```
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item> 
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

to your AppTheme style file, after remove, then you can not use default actionbar to add tabs.

If you still want to use tabs, then you have to use SlidingTabLayout to make a custom ViewPager title strip. There is Android sample project [SlidingTabsBasic](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/project.html), which show detail how to make custom tabs.